# Remove default padding from Flutter slider [Syncfusion flutter slider]

Tags: flutter, slider

I have this slider that looks as follows:

[image]

So What I want is to make the slider track take the complete width and the thumb always remain inside the track. Currently, the track doesn't take the complete width by itself, it also considers half of the thumb width to size the track. Also, the thumb is not completely inside the track currently, it is half outside. The code for this slider is as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_core/theme.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_sliders/sliders.dart';

class CustomSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomSlider({
    super.key,
    required this.min,
    required this.max,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.showInfinity = false,
    this.stepSize,
  });

  final double min;
  final double max;
  final Function(double) onChanged;
  final bool showInfinity;
  final double? stepSize;

  @override
  State<CustomSlider> createState() => _CustomSliderState();
}

class _CustomSliderState extends State<CustomSlider> {
  late double _value;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _value = widget.min;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfSliderTheme(
      data: SfSliderThemeData(
        activeTrackHeight: 50,
        inactiveTrackHeight: 50,
        thumbRadius: 25,
        thumbColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        activeTrackColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        inactiveTrackColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(.2),
      ),
      child: SfSlider(
        value: _value,
        min: widget.min,
        max: widget.max,
        onChanged: (value) {
          widget.onChanged(value);

          setState(() {
            _value = value;
          });
        },
        stepSize: widget.stepSize,
        thumbIcon: Center(
          child: widget.showInfinity && _value == widget.max
              ? const Icon(
                  Icons.all_inclusive,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 20,
                )
              : Text(
                  '${_value.toInt()}s',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using the Syncfusion flutter packages to achieve this style.